# Can't Connect AWS MySQL in EC2 from remote system

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am unable to connect the mysql in aws from my local system.I had added MYSQL rule in security groups (TCP) and port:3306.Even though I am not able to access that.

Comment: Is OS firewall open? Is MySQL service up? Can you SSH into that instance? What is the error that you get when you try to connect? Does `netstat` show that mysql is listening?...

Answer (score 0):

Check out your config mysql file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and be sure that the mysql server accepts incoming connections.
More detalis: [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)